# How do I do type checking before casting using pydantic?

Tags: python, validation, types, python-3.7, pydantic

I created a class using the dataclass decorator of pydantic and I want to check the type of an argument before it becomes an attribute of the class. This is my code:

```py
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
from pydantic import validator

@dataclass
class Person(object):
    name: Optional[str] = None

    @validator('name')
    def name_must_be_str(cls, v):
        if type(v) is not str:
            raise TypeError("'name' must be str, not " + type(v).__name__)
        return v
```

Now when I create an instance like person = Person(12), the argument becomes a string, too ('12'). How can I check the type before the instance casts the argument to a string?

Comment: Did Pydantic used to implicitly convert `v` to a `str`?  `Person(12)` raises a type error without any explicit validator in version 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with pydantic before so the following may be not the best solution, but according to the [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/#initialize-hooks) you can use `__post_init__` dunder method of `dataclass` in order to run code before the value is cast to the specified type:

```
from typing import Optional

from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
from pydantic import validator


@dataclass
class Person:
    name: Optional[str] = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        if not isinstance(self.name, str):
            print(f'Careful! Your name, {self.name}, is not a string!')

    @validator('name')
    def name_must_be_str(cls, v):
        if type(v) is not str:
            raise TypeError("'name' must be str, not " + type(v).__name__)
        return v


print(Person(1))
# Careful! Your name, 1, is not a string!
# Person(name='1')
```

There are also [pre-validators](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/#pre-and-whole-validators) which can be specified as `@validator('name', pre=True)`, and they also run the code before casting:

```
@dataclass
class Person:
    name: Optional[str] = None

    @validator('name', pre=True)
    def name_must_be_str(cls, v):
        if type(v) is not str:
            raise TypeError("'name' must be str, not " + type(v).__name__)
        return v


print(Person(1))
```

But for me, they return two identical errors for some reason:

```
ValidationError: 2 validation errors
name
  'name' must be str, not int (type=type_error)
name
  'name' must be str, not int (type=type_error)
```